# strdup a char * within structure within a structure causing loss in valgrind

Tags: c

I am currently learning C and trying to debug an issue with a program.

I've snippets of the code into a separate test program and have managed to replicate the fault but I can't see for the life of me where its going wrong. I think its most likely I'm screwing up a pointer somewhere but not sure where.

Below is my code:

```
typedef int BOOL;
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct CallLogSearchDataStruct
{
    char * target;
    float duration;
    struct CallLogSearchOutboundStruct * outboundLegs;
} callLogSearchDataStruct;

typedef struct CallLogSearchOutboundStruct
{
    char * target;
    float duration;
    BOOL allowOverwrite;
    struct CallLogSearchOutboundStruct *nextLeg;
} callLogSearchOutboundStruct;

callLogSearchOutboundStruct *insertOutboundLegtoList(callLogSearchOutboundStruct ** outboundLeg, char * target, float duration, BOOL overwriteFirstoutboundLegs);
void freeCallLogSearchDataStruct(callLogSearchDataStruct *callLogSearchData, int count);
void clearOutboundLinkedList(callLogSearchOutboundStruct **outboundLeg);
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i = 0;
    int count = 10;
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct * outboundCallLegStartPtr = NULL;
    callLogSearchDataStruct * callLogSearchData = NULL;
    callLogSearchData = calloc(count, sizeof(callLogSearchDataStruct));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {   
    asprintf(&callLogSearchData[i].target, "Target %i", i);
    callLogSearchData[i].duration = i * 10;

    callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs = malloc(sizeof(callLogSearchOutboundStruct));
    callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs->target = NULL;
    callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs->nextLeg = NULL;

    outboundCallLegStartPtr = callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs;
    insertOutboundLegtoList(&outboundCallLegStartPtr, "OutboundTarget", i, FALSE);
    }

    freeCallLogSearchDataStruct(callLogSearchData, count);
    free(callLogSearchData);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

callLogSearchOutboundStruct *insertOutboundLegtoList(callLogSearchOutboundStruct ** outboundLeg, char * target, float duration, BOOL overwriteFirstoutboundLegs)
{
    if (target == NULL)
    {
    return *outboundLeg;
    }

    if (!*outboundLeg)
    {
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct *newOutboundLeg = NULL;
    newOutboundLeg = malloc(sizeof(*newOutboundLeg));

    newOutboundLeg->nextLeg = NULL;
    newOutboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
    newOutboundLeg->duration = duration;
    newOutboundLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
    *outboundLeg = newOutboundLeg;
    return newOutboundLeg;
    }
    if (overwriteFirstoutboundLegs == TRUE)
    {
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct * currentLeg = *outboundLeg;
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct * temp;

    free(currentLeg->target);
    currentLeg->target = strdup(target);
    currentLeg->duration = duration;
    currentLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
    temp = currentLeg->nextLeg;
    while (temp)
    {
        temp->allowOverwrite = TRUE;
        temp = temp->nextLeg;
    }
    return currentLeg;
    }
    else
    {
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct **ptr = outboundLeg;
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct *currentLeg = *outboundLeg;

    if (currentLeg->target == NULL)
    {
        //This strdup is causing the loss record
        currentLeg->target = strdup(target);
        currentLeg->duration = duration;
        currentLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
        *ptr = currentLeg;
        return currentLeg;
    }
    else
    {
        while (currentLeg && currentLeg->allowOverwrite == FALSE)
        {
        ptr = &currentLeg->nextLeg;
        currentLeg = currentLeg->nextLeg;
        }
        if (currentLeg)
        {
        currentLeg->target = strdup(target);
        currentLeg->duration = duration;
        currentLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
        *ptr = currentLeg;
        return currentLeg;
        }
        else
        {
        currentLeg = malloc(sizeof(*currentLeg));
        currentLeg->nextLeg = NULL;
        currentLeg->target = strdup(target);
        currentLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
        currentLeg->duration = duration;
        *ptr = currentLeg;
        }
    }
    return currentLeg;
    }
}

void freeCallLogSearchDataStruct(callLogSearchDataStruct *callLogSearchData, int count)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
    if (callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs != NULL)
    {
        clearOutboundLinkedList(&callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs);
        free(callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs);
    }
    free(callLogSearchData[i].target);
    }
}

void clearOutboundLinkedList(callLogSearchOutboundStruct **outboundLeg)
{
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct *currentStruct = *outboundLeg;
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct *temp;

    while (currentStruct->nextLeg != NULL)
    {
        temp = currentStruct;
        currentStruct = currentStruct->nextLeg;
        free(temp->target);
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Below is the output from valgrind

```
==10626== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10626==     in use at exit: 150 bytes in 10 blocks
==10626==   total heap usage: 41 allocs, 31 frees, 1,520 bytes allocated
==10626==
==10626== Searching for pointers to 10 not-freed blocks
==10626== Checked 47,612 bytes
==10626==
==10626== 150 bytes in 10 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==10626==    at 0x40072D5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==10626==    by 0xB0798F: strdup (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==10626==    by 0x80486F9: insertOutboundLegtoList (main.c:115)
==10626==    by 0x80485BA: main (main.c:55)
==10626==
==10626== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10626==    definitely lost: 150 bytes in 10 blocks
==10626==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10626==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10626==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10626==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10626==
==10626== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 8)
```

As you can see from the comment in the code I check if currentLeg->target is NULL and if so I strdup a char * into this variable but Valgrind is reporting that this strdup is getting lost but I can't see how. I can only be writing to it once due to the counter and I'm freeing the structures so not sure where to look.

Comment: Too much to read!!... Please try to make it more concise.

Comment: That is consise. I've pointed out where the problem is and I'm showing you where I am freeing the structures, in my opinion you need to see where I'm allocating and free'ing to be able to help

Comment: I haven't followed all of the logic through, but `while (currentStruct->nextLeg != NULL)` in your last function looks suspicious - it'll never free the last node of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your problem, it is in this sample of code:

```
`
    if (currentLeg)
       {
           currentLeg->target = strdup(target);
           currentLeg->duration = duration;
           currentLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
           *ptr = currentLeg;
           return currentLeg;
       }
`
```

In facts when you come in this condition your currentLeg already got its targets linked to a duuped char* array, It would be good to check if `currentLeg->target != NULL` and then free it:

```
`
    if (currentLeg)
       {
           if (currentLeg->target != NULL)
              free(currentLeg->target);
           currentLeg->target = strdup(target);
           currentLeg->duration = duration;
           currentLeg->allowOverwrite = FALSE;
           *ptr = currentLeg;
           return currentLeg;
       }
`
```

**Edit:** I found and patch your error:

**change**

```
`
      if (callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs != NULL)
        {
          clearOutboundLinkedList(&callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs);
          free(callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs);
        }
`
```

**to**

```
`
      if (callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs != NULL)
        {
          clearOutboundLinkedList(&callLogSearchData[i].outboundLegs);
        }
`
```

**and change** `while (currentStruct->nextLeg != NULL)` **to** `while (currentStruct != NULL)`
In facts the en of your linked list was never freed correctly
(btw sorry form my bad english)

Comment: Thanks your right in the sense that would have given me another problem, although I don't think this part of the code is actually getting utilised currently. I've added it in anyway and rebuilt but I'm still getting the same error from Valgrind in the if statement above

Comment: Is it normal you never go into the `while (currentStruct->nextLeg != NULL)` ?

Comment: Thanks you're right the loop was the problem, I've kept the while loop the same however but after the loop I then free(currentStruct) and then Valgrind says there are no errors

Comment: that was the over solution in my head..; glad you found it!